# What minimal value of parameter will give nontrivial solution to the equation?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

The second order ODE is given:

$y''(x) + (\lambda - x^2) y(x) = 0$ with boundary conditions $y(0) = y(1) = 0$

The question is: what minimal value of $\lambda$ will make it have nontrivial solution?